# Remove all instances of specific value from comma separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, csv, t-sql

I want to remove a given value (e.g. `1`) from the following string without splitting or using XML functionality.

```
/* input:  */ @ObjectValue = '1,121,4,5,1,111,131,1'
/* output: */ '121,4,5,111,131'
```

Comment: what is the condition ? Always the first and last ? Or Always `1` ? You need to specify the rules and condition

Comment: This is (one of the) reason(s) you should never store cvs data. Normalize your data, and you'll never have this problem.

Comment: This is going to be one ugly query.  I recommend avoiding using CSV in this manner.  If you bring your data into SQL Server, you should normalize it.

Comment: Which sql server version are you using?

Comment: All '1' whether at the start,middle or end

Comment: Sql server 2016

Comment: Suggestion is to use @Vasily's method listed below, and create a properly normalized view of the data to query against (without filtering out the 1's).  It will save you a bunch of headaches in the future.

Comment: @user2366842 that's right but i have single value stored for configuration so, i don't think it impact more in database.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method is:

```
SELECT TRIM(',' from REPLACE(',' + @ObjectValue  + ',', ',1,', ','))
```

`TRIM()` is not available in older versions of SQL Server.  One method is to replace the commas with spaces and using the available trim functions:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(',' + @ObjectValue + ',', ',1,', ','), ',', ' '))), ' ', ','),
```

Comment: Need to replace `,1,` rather than just `,1`?  *(And replace with `, `?)*

Comment: Fails for `1,100,1` (leaves `00`)

Comment: @Deeppatel . . . There was a typo.  All those commas and quotes, it is hard to keep track of which goes where.  The value to replace is `',1,'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double the delimiters in the list so that `1,1,1` becomes `,1,,1,,1,`. Then replace all `,1,` and cleanup afterwards:

```
SELECT ObjectValue, REPLACE(
    LTRIM(RTRIM(
        REPLACE(' ' + REPLACE(ObjectValue, ',', '  ') + ' ', ' 1 ', '')
    )), '  ', ','
)
FROM (VALUES
    ('1'),
    ('1,1'),
    ('1,1,1'),
    ('0,1,0'),
    ('0,1,1,0'),
    ('0,1,1,1,0'),
    ('0,1,0,1,0'),
    ('1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1')
) AS v(ObjectValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- SSMS 2017
DECLARE @ObjectValue VARCHAR(100) = '1,121,4,5,1,111,131,1'
SELECT TRIM(',' FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(',' + @ObjectValue  + ',', ',1,', ','),',1,', ','))

-- SSMS 2016 or earlier 

    DECLARE @Replacetxt VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @ObjectValue=REPLACE(REPLACE(','+@ObjectValue+',', ',1,', ','), ',1,', ',') --Replace ',1,' with ','

    SET @Replacetxt=REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@ObjectValue, PATINDEX('%[^,]%', @ObjectValue), LEN(@ObjectValue))) -- Remove comma from starting and reverse string

    SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Replacetxt, PATINDEX('%[^,]%', @Replacetxt), LEN(@ObjectValue))) -- Remove comma from ending and reverse string
```

Comment: Fails for `1,1,1,1`.